# I want to move files in Shell

Tags: shell, file, move

I have two folder `xyz` and `Bin`. I want to move `xyz` directory and it's sub directory as well to `Bin` folder. 
I want output like this:

```
Bin/xyz/q.html
       /images/0.gif
```

How can do move files and subdirectory and I will get that type of output.

Comment: Why does `mv` not work for you?

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail? Note that general questions about usage of UNIX tools belong on [unix.se], not Stack Overflow; for a question to be topical here, you should be asking a question that's clearly about *writing code*, typically with a [mcve] allowing others to reproduce a specific, narrow error.

Answer (score 0):

Move (mv) can be thought of as rename. If mv is used to move a file from one drive to another, then a copy will be made and the original will be deleted.

If the file is a directory (folder), then all of the contents of that directory are also moved.

```
$ mv -v xyz Bin
```

moves the file called xyz, no matter what kind of file it is, even if it is a directory, into the existing directory called Bin. If Bin does not exist, then the move command will rename xyz to Bin.

If you only want to move a few files, for example, Bin/1.html is to be moved to Bin/xyz/1.html, then file being moved is a file called 1.html (not a directory called bin or xyz).

```
$ mv -v Bin/1.html Bin/xyz/1.html
```

will perform the move if the Bin/xyz exists and is a directory. If directory Bin/xyz does not exist, then this mv command will error because mv does not create parent destination directories.

```
$ mkdir -v Bin/xyz
```

will create an empty directory called xyz in an existing directory called Bin. Then files can be moved into the existing Bin/xyz directory.

The -v (--verbose) tells mv and mkdir to report what happened. The output that they produce given a success is what -v does. The most common way to list the content of a directory is ls, but the indentation that you desire will require some programming.

```
$ man mv
$ man mkdir
```

will show all the features of the mv an mkdir commands.

Comment: But if in `xyz` folder there are 4 files. I want to move only 2 files in `Bin` folder. I run that command only the `xyz` file will move. they can not move the directory.

Comment: for example `Bin/1.html` `Bin/image/2.gif` I want `Bin/xyz/1.html` `Bin/image/2.gif`.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet point therein regarding questions which "are not about programming [as defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" -- a definition which pointedly includes the phrase "*unique to software development*" **AND**ed, not **OR**ed, into other conditions.